# cURL multi save result in db with charset problems

Tags: php, curl, character-encoding

I using a script which use multi curl to parse 100k urls but sometimes if site is in russian, chinese, japanese, or others strange languages it save like this:

```
ͧ�����ǡ�ȹҫ�
```

Save in my db with strange characters... I tried with iconv or mb_convert_encoding but seems don't wanna work. What can i do?

Comment: Give code example, and what have you tried?

Comment: I tried my iconv/mv_conver_encoding with my $result variable which is the source code of every url